# Animate CSS value left and opacity doesn't work with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

Here is the code. I can't make opacity animate as well.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title></title>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <style type="text/css">
            body{
                background: #000;
                color: #fff;
                font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
            }
            .menu{
                position: absolute;
                top: 10px;
                left: 0px;
                z-index: 11;
                width: 700px;
                height: 60px;
            }
            .menu a{
                background-color: #808080;
                margin-bottom: 2px;
                display: inline;
                width: 150px;
                height: 60px;
                color: #fff;
                line-height: 60px;
                text-align: center;
                text-transform: uppercase;
                outline: none;
            }
            .menu a:hover{
                color: #000;
                background-color: #fff;
            }
            #main-wrapper{
                position: absolute;
                left: 1000px;
                top: 10px;
                width: 900px;
                height: 380px;
                background-color: #000;
                opacity: 0.1;
                filter: alpha(opacity=10);
                -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=10)";
                filter: alpha(opacity=10);
                z-index: 9999;
                zoom: 1;
                color: #fff;
            }
            #main-wrapper .active{
                display: block;
            }
            .id-two{
                padding: 10px;
                display: none;
            }
            .id-three{
                padding: 10px;
                display: none;
            }
            .id-four{
                padding: 10px;
                display: none;
            }
            #slider_window{
                position: relative;
                left: 110px;
                width: 85%;
                height: 400px;
                background-color: #8ae234;
                overflow: hidden;
                top: 120px;
            }
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            jQuery(document).ready(function($){
                var current_elem_class;

                var close_active_page = function(current_id){

                    if(current_id != current_elem_class){
                        var left_position = '1000px';
                        $("#main-wrapper").stop().animate({
                            opacity : 0.1,
                            left :  left_position
                        }, {
                            "duration": 700,
                            //"easing": "easeInOutBack",
                            complete: function(){
                                //alert('complete');
                                if(typeof current_elem_class != 'undefined'){
                                    $("div." + current_elem_class).removeClass('active');
                                    current_elem_class = current_id;
                                    if(current_id != 'id-one'){
                                        open_non_active_page("div." + current_elem_class);
                                    }
                                }else{
                                    current_elem_class = current_id;
                                    if(current_id != 'id-one'){
                                        open_non_active_page("div." + current_elem_class);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }

                var open_non_active_page = function(elem){

                    var left_position = '10px';

                    $(elem).addClass('active');

                    $("#main-wrapper").stop().animate({
                        opacity : 0.6,
                        left: left_position
                    },{
                        "duration": 700,
                        //"easing": "easeInOutBack",
                        complete: function(){
                            $("#main-wrapper").stop().animate({
                                opacity : 1.0,
                                left: left_position
                            },{
                                "duration": 1000
                            });
                        }
                    });
                }

                $("a.button").bind('click',function(){
                    close_active_page($(this).attr('id'));
                });
            })
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="menu" class="menu">
            <a href="#" id="id-one" class="button close_all">Close all</a>
            <a href="#" id="id-two" class="button">Close all - Open Two</a>
            <a href="#" id="id-three" class="button">Close all - Open Three</a>
            <a href="#" id="id-four" class="button">Close all - Open Four</a>
        </div>
        <div id="slider_window">
            <div id="main-wrapper" class="">
                <div class="id-two">
                    <p><h2>Two</h2><br />Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent adipiscing, magna a porttitor consequat, libero augue gravida lacus, vitae blandit elit eros sed sem. Pellentesque convallis aliquam ante at pretium. Nam at semper ligula. Integer blandit tellus in libero accumsan eleifend. Maecenas hendrerit ante velit. Aenean ultricies vehicula iaculis. Aliquam id orci et lacus egestas elementum. Aliquam erat volutpat. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Aliquam viverra sollicitudin tortor, at ultricies enim mollis ut. Etiam facilisis vulputate justo, sed venenatis justo ullamcorper porta.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="id-three">
                    <p><h2>Three</h2><br />Aliquam id orci et lacus egestas elementum. Aliquam erat volutpat. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Aliquam viverra sollicitudin tortor, at ultricies enim mollis ut. Etiam facilisis vulputate justo, sed venenatis justo ullamcorper porta.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="id-four">
                    <p><h2>Four</h2><br />Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit lacus, cula iaculis. Aliquam id orci et lacus egestas elementum. Aliquam erat volutpat. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibutor, at ultricies enim mollis ut. Etiam faci</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to use stop() function on open_non_active_page. In this chain of events when 
close_active_page is called it will stop any opening animation.

```
 var open_non_active_page = function(elem) {

        var left_position = '10px';

        $(elem).addClass('active');

        $("#main-wrapper").animate({
            opacity: 0.6,
            left: left_position
        }, 700, function() {

            $("#main-wrapper").animate({
                opacity: 1.0,
                left: left_position
            }, {
                queue: false,
                duration: 1000
            });
        });

    }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ywre2/5/

Comment: Tnx,one question, how this queue:false solved the issue ? I have tried that,but I have put it on every animation.

Comment: queue:false is not the solution. just removing the stop() methods. queue:false is another option when working with animations, instead of stop(). i just left it there as an option. here it doesn't do anything, so you can remove it. http://css-tricks.com/examples/jQueryStop/

Comment: Ohhhhhh,thank you,now I see that stop is removed,thanks for the  link

Answer (score 2):

You need

```
left : "+=" + left_position
```

or

```
left : "-=" + left_position
```